# How to initialize integer pointer inside a structure while declaration?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
struct test_stub  
{  
   int n;  
   int *array;  
   char *b;
}  
test[3]=  
{  
   {5,{1,2,3,4,5},"abcd"}  
};  
int main()  
{    

    return 0;  
}
```

but this is not working
error i'm getting is int cannot be used to initialize int *
if it is character pointer we can initialize it in between " " these

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to initialize your structure object at declaration time, use a compound literal:

```
struct test_stub
{
    int n;
    int *array;
    char *b;
 }
 test[3]=
 {
    {5,(int [5]){1,2,3,4,5},"abcd"}
 };
```

or if your array is of fixed size, change the type of `array` from `int *` to `int [5]`:

```
struct test_stub
{
    int n;
    int array[5];
    char *b;
 }
 test[3]=
 {
    {5,{1,2,3,4,5},"abcd"}
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I'm still getting error in visual studio when used this {5,(int [5]){1,2,3,4,5},"abcd"} .The error i'm getting is type name is not allowed

Comment: @user3365619 compound literals are a c99 feature but Visual Studio does not support c99.

Comment: @ouah can the pointer `array` be passed to `free` in the first case? Where is the memory allocated for the array it points to?

Comment: @ajay no, the array has static storage duration here.

Comment: @ouah Thanks for clarifying. :) Please add this to your answer and also that it's a C99 feature to make your answer complete.